# Run-time Error '438' on one user's computer

Tags: excel, vba

I have put together an admittedly rough macro to quickly sort and make changes to CSVs of transactions from a payment provider. This macro works fine on every computer I have tested it on except for one Windows 10 machine.

Any help would be great =)

Here is the error and here is the troublesome code:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ScssT.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5owe1.png

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Can you cut and paste the code and error to the question? That would make it so people don't have to browse back and forth between pages. You can use triple backticks to format a coding block.

Comment: Try using `SortFields.Add` instead of `.Add2`  https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/1072594-vba-difference-sort-add2-add-sortfields-add2-vs-sortfields-add.html

Comment: @TimWilliams Thank you! That fixed my issue.

Comment: @aschultz Thank you for your help, I will make sure any future questions that I have are more appropriately formatted =).